# how to pass time to textview from timepicker which are inside tab and that extends fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, timepicker

I am new in android and  I am trying to pass result of time picker to textview by clicking on button (here i am using tabbed layout), the problem is i did not get any output, i do not know whether it is working or not.
Can anyone please help me figure this out?

```
 public class Tabwhen extends Fragment {
        @Nullable
        @Override

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.when, container, false);

            final TextView time;
            final TimePicker timePicker;

            time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.set_time1);
            timePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
            Button set_time = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_set_time);

            set_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                            // display a toast with changed values of time picker
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), hourOfDay + " : " + minute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            time.setText(hourOfDay +":"+ minute); // set the current time in text view
                        }
                    });


                }





       });

            return view;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this

so define A private String like mSelectedTime;

```
final TextView time = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) mView.findViewById(R.id.dp);

timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        mSelectedTime = hourOfDay + " " + ":" + " " +minute;
    }
});
```

and then in your listener :

```
set_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         time.setText(mSelectedTime)
}
```

Comment: the point is in "setOnTimeChangedListener" instead of "setOnClickListener"

Comment: why you write your listener inside onClick listener?

Comment: i want to show time to textview by clicking on button

Comment: separate two onClick listeners